# How to know if a sum is less than a given number

Tags: calculus

It is given that $\frac{1}{2^j}>\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}$.

So is it true that $\sum\limits_{n=j+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{2^j}$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=j+1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{j+1}}+ \frac{1}{2^{j+2}}+ \frac{1}{2^{j+3}}\dots$ so the terms get smaller and smaller, that is all I know

Comment: You can compute the sum first using formula for sum of geometric series and then compare.
$$~\\~$$Remember this : If all the terms of a given sum is less than a given number, it doesn't necessarily imply that the sum is also less than the given number. A simple counter example would be the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}$ and the given number $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider the case where $j=0$. We have that $1>\frac{1}{2}$ but $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^j}}=2$$. Subtracting the first term and using the sum formula for a geometric series we get $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^j}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1$$

This gives us that $\frac{1}{2^j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}}$ when $j=0$.